# How to extract the text ignoring the nested tag where i need the text in <td> but not in nested <strong>

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I want to ignore a nested  tag in `<td>` in code below. 
I just want integers(number) in `<td>` not text which is included in `<strong>` tag. 
I have written selenium code but it is returning whole text in `<td>.`
Is there any method by which i ignore nested  and get number which is in `<td>`

Python Code:

```
 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#middle > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td')))
 data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#middle > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td")
    print(data[0].text)
```

> OUTPUT:: Parcel Number 71200000

But I only want 71200000

HTML :

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="">
            <td><strong>Parcel Number</strong> 71200000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td><strong>Tax Area</strong> 19A - TAX DISTRICT 19A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td><strong>Situs Address</strong> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="">
            <td><strong>Legal Summary</strong> W.H.M. SECTION A BLK 1 LOT 1 CONT. 7.14 AC</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can apply a regex to extract the number.

Comment: but for other <td> i can't apply regex. e.g
<td><strong>Tax Area</strong> 19A - TAX DISTRICT 19A</td>
In this i need :  19A - TAX DISTRICT 19A only

Comment: You will have to manipulate the text that you got. I can provide in java, but seems you need in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The following code may help you.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#middle > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td')))
    data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#middle > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td")
    print(data[0].text)
    data_child = data[0].find_element_by_tag_name("strong")
    data_parent = data[0].text.replace(data_child.text,'')
    print(data_parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can do something like -

```
data.substring(data.indexOf("</strong>")+"</strong>".length(), data .length()));
```

May be you can convert it : )

Answer (score 0):

Using regex.

```
import re
output = "Parcel Number 71200000"
m = re.search(r"\d+", output)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
71200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **decompose** function to remove the text in `<strong>` tag and get only text in `<td>` tag.

```
content = BeautifulSoup(yourhtml, 'html.parser')
tds = content.find_all('td')
tds[0].find("strong").decompose()
print(tds[0].text.strip())
```

output:
71200000

Answer (score 0):

To extract the desired texts you can also use *Python's* [**`split()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method as follows:

```
all_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#middle > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td')))
for data in all_data:
    print(data.text.split(">")[2])
```

Comment: whole text in <td> , it's not ignoring "strong" tag

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @curious_nustian Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status